# Resizing a picture in <div> next to a sidebar

Tags: html, css

I need to place a picture in a box on the right of the sidebar. div-box has certain size and border.

If i set the style to a picture, it enlarges to the size of the box, when i need it to be 100%.

If i set the style to a box, the box' borders expand to a sidebar.

Please advise.

```css
.sidebar {
    background: white;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 46px 46px 46px;
}

.sidebar-button{
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 240px;
    border-top: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    border-right: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    border-left: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.auto {
    border-bottom: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
}

.sidebar-button:hover{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 220px;
}

.bike-picture {
    border: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    margin: 40px 46px 46px 26px;
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 40px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Ноутбуки</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Планшеты</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телефоны</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телевизоры</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Бытовая техника</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button auto" href="#">Автотовары</a>  
</div>
<div class="bike-picture">
    <img src="img/bike.png" alt="Bike">
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwA4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

check this one:

```css
.container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    flex-flow: row nowrap;

    -webkit-align-items: flex-start; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    align-items: flex-start;
    
    padding: 40px 0 46px 0;
    background-color: white;
    
}
.sidebar {
    height: 240px;
    flex-basis: 240px;
    padding: 0 46px 0 46px;
}

.sidebar-button{
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 240px;
    border-top: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    border-right: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    border-left: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.auto {
    border-bottom: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
}

.sidebar-button:hover{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 220px;
}

.bike-picture {
    border: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.bike-picture img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Ноутбуки</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Планшеты</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телефоны</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телевизоры</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Бытовая техника</a>  
    <a class="sidebar-button auto" href="#">Автотовары</a>  
</div>
<div class="bike-picture">
    <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/fpyql332l/felt_bicycles_q26_194648_1.jpg" alt="Bike">
</div>
</div>
```